# an issue when start websphere server?

Tags: java, websphere

I have an issue with my IBM websphere server to run an web application. Sometimes, when I start websphere, It faces an issue some class from module `MyApp.war`. The issue make me can not login to my web application.

```
W com.ibm.ws.amm.scan.context.ScannerContextImpl getInputDataForClass Failed to open resource [ com/aia/lms/MyClass.class ] from module [ MyApp.war ]
```

Is there any way to know the root cause to fix this issue.

Comment: this is just a warning, not error. the 'not logging in' issue might be because of some logical/config errors. Make sure context path is set and used properly.

Answer (score 0):

To find the root cause of the warning you need to know how your application is using com/aia/lms/MyClass.class.   WebSphere Application Server is not able to find this class during a scan for annotations.  It's possible the class isn't in your application, but it is a super class of a class in your application.

In many cases the warning message is harmless.  For example, your application doesn't use the class or the class and it's super classes do not contain annotations.

As of WebSphere Application Server 8.5.5.13 and 9.0.0.5, you can turn off this warning.  The recommended way to do that is to update the MANIFEST.MF of the WAR by adding the following line:

Reduce-AMM-Warning-Messages: true

Be careful when [editing MANIFEST.MF](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/modman.html) since specific format rules apply.  For example, the file needs to end with a newline or carriage return.

For more information, see the documentation for [APAR PI82698](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1PI82698).